# Reading and writing files

Tags: file, python-3.x

I am trying to read one text file and convert the contents of that file to pig latin on a new file. Here is what I have:

```
def pl_line(word):
    statement = input('enter a string: ')

    words = statement.split()

    for word in words:
        if len(word) <= 1:
            print(word + 'ay')
        else:
            print(word[1:] + word[0] + 'ay')


def pl_file(old_file, new_file):
    old_file = input('enter the file you want to read from: ')
    new_file = input('enter the file you would like to write to: ')

    write_to = open(new_file, 'w')
    read_from = open(old_file, 'r')

    lines = read_from.readlines()
    for line in lines():
        line = pl_line(line.strip('\n'))
        write_to.write(line + '\n')
    read_from.close()
    write_to.close()
```

However, when I run this, I get this error message:
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Any ideas of how to improve my code?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some improvements to the actual converter:

```
_VOWELS = 'aeiou'
_VOWELS_Y = _VOWELS + 'y'
_SILENT_H_WORDS = "hour honest honor heir herb".split()

def igpay_atinlay(word:str, with_vowel:str='yay'):
    is_title = False
    if word.title() == word:
        is_title = True
        word = word.lower()

    # Default case, strangely, is 'in-yay'
    result = word + with_vowel

    if not word[0] in _VOWELS and not word in _SILENT_H_WORDS:
        for pos in range(1, len(word)):
            if word[pos] in _VOWELS:
                result = word[pos:] + word[0:pos] + 'ay'
                break

    if is_title:
        result = result.title()

    return result

def line_to_pl(line:str, with_vowel:str='yay'):
    new_line = ''

    start = None
    for pos in range(0, len(line)):
        if line[pos].isalpha() or line[pos] == "'" or line[pos] == "-":
            if start is None:
                start = pos
        else:
            if start is not None:
                new_line += igpay_atinlay(line[start:pos], with_vowel=with_vowel)
                start = None
            new_line += line[pos]

    if start is not None:
        new_line += igpay_atinlay(line[start:pos], with_vowel=with_vowel)
        start = None

    return new_line

tests = """
Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their party!
Onward, Christian soldiers!
A horse! My kingdom for a horse!
Ng!
Run away!
This is it.
Help, I need somebody.
Oh, my!
Dr. Livingston, I presume?
"""

for t in tests.split("\n"):
    if t:
        print(t)
        print(line_to_pl(t))
```

Answer (score 0):

You very likely mixed up the assignments to `read_from`and `write_to`, so you're unintentionally trying to read from a file opened only for write access.

Comment: you were right, i have edited my original question with a new error message that i was presented with

Comment: The problem is the call to `lines` (the parentheses) in the `for` clause. You could have found that out very easily by reading the whole traceback; it points you to the line numbers for any code on the stack at which the error occurs. Start from the place in your code listed last and, if you don't see the cause for the problem there, work your way up the traceback.